# Use numpy to mask an image with a pattern?

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy

I'm using numpy to build pixel arrays.  An 800x600 image is an 3-dimensional array of uint8, 800x600x3.  I also have a similar array with a fixed pattern (a checkerboard, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169478/how-to-make-a-checkerboard-in-numpy)). I have another array, 800x600 of mask values.  Where the mask is zero, I want to copy the pattern pixel to the image pixel.  Where the mask is not zero, I want to leave the image pixel alone.

```
>>> image.shape
(800, 600, 3)
>>> chex.shape
(800, 600, 3)
>>> mask.shape
(800, 600)
```

This feels like it should work:

```
image[mask == 0,...] = chex
```

but gives "ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape".

What do I use to copy chex pixels to image pixels where mask is zero?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
idx=(mask==0)
image[idx]=chex[idx]
```

Note that `image` has shape (800,600,3), while `idx` has shape (800,600). [The rules](http://docs.scipy.org/numpy/docs/numpy-docs/reference/arrays.indexing.rst/#arrays-indexing) for indexing state

> if the selection tuple is smaller than
>   n, then as many : objects as needed
>   are added to the **end** of the selection
>   tuple so that the modified selection
>   tuple has length N.

Thus indexing arrays have a sort of broadcasting ability of their own. `idx`'s shape gets promoted to (800,600,:)

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to illustrate an example using @unutbu answer. In this scenario, I have an image of a cat that I rotate. This rotation causes some black edges that look ugly especially when pasted on a non-black background.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import rotate


cat = plt.imread('cat.jpeg')
bg = plt.imread('background.jpeg')


rotcat = rotate(cat, angle=8, reshape=True) ## rotating creates some black edges
height, width, _ = rotcat.shape

bgcopy = bg.copy() ## create a copy of the background; paste on copy

x, y = 40, 50 
bgcopy[x:x+height, y:y+width] = rotcat
plt.imsave('cat-on-bg-mask.jpg', bgcopy)
```

[image: bad pasting]

So, I find the areas of the mask and replace those values with the original background values

```
mask_ind = (bgcopy == 0)
bgcopy[mask_ind] = bg[mask_ind]
plt.imsave('cat-on-bg.jpg', bgcopy)
```

[image: good pasting]

I should also note that `PIL.Image` (from the `Pillow` library) has the ability to paste an image onto another image with fewer steps.

Answer (score 4):

I found it easiest to create a mask wherein 1 = "pixel to keep" and 0 = "pixel to remove".

Then I multiplied my image by that mask to remove the unwanted pixels. Example to retain only the frame (outside) of a portrait:

```
from scipy.misc import imread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

im = imread('portrait.jpg', mode='L') # read in image
plt.imshow(im) # show the original image
```

[image]

```
mask = np.ones(im.shape) # create a mask with the image's shape
bw = 0.1 # identify border width and height as fraction of image size
bx = int(im.shape[1] * bw) # get the x dimension border width
by = int(im.shape[0] * bw) # get the y dimension border height
mask[bx:-bx,by:-by] = 0 # create a mask with 1 for border and 0 for inside

masked = im * mask # multiply `im` by the mask to zero out non-border pixels
plt.imshow(masked) # show the result of the masking operation
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
image[mask[:] == 0,...] = chex[mask[:] == 0,...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used arrays of 8x6x3, 8x6x3, and 8x6 to represent your image array, checker array, and mask array respectively.

```
# first create mini-versions of your arrays:
mask = NP.random.random_integers(0, 1, 48).reshape(8, 6)
img = NP.random.random_integers(3, 9, 8*6*3).reshape(8, 6, 3)
chk = NP.ones((8, 6, 3))

# all the work done in these two lines
mask = mask[:,:,NP.newaxis]
res = NP.where(mask==0, chk, img)
```

Comment: The shapes of the three images, `mask.shape (8, 6), chk.shape (8, 6, 3) and img.shape (8, 6, 3)` seems not to match the requirement of `np.where.`