# Designing a Kernel for a support vector machine (XOR)

Tags: kernel, machine-learning, svm

The meat of my question is "how does one design a kernel function for a learning problem?"

As a quick background, I'm reading books on support vector machines and kernel machines, and everywhere I look authors give examples of kernels (polynomial kernels both homogeneous and nonhomogeneous, gaussian kernels, and allusions to text-based kernels to name a few), but all either provide pictures of the results without specifying the kernel, or vaguely claim that "an efficient kernel can be constructed". I'm interested in the process that goes on when one designs a kernel for a new problem.

Probably the easiest example is learning XOR, a smallest (4 points) non-linear data set as embedded the real plane. How would one come up with a natural (and non-trivial) kernel to linearly separate this data?

As a more complex example (see Cristianini, Introduction to SVMs, figure 6.2), how would one design a kernel to learn a checkerboard pattern? Cristianini states the picture was derived "using Gaussian kernels" but it seems that he uses multiple, and they are combined and modified in an unspecified way.

If this question is too broad to answer here, I'd appreciate a reference to the construction of one such kernel function, though I'd prefer the example be somewhat simple.

Comment: Have you implement xor logic gate with svm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Q: "How does one design a kernel function for a learning problem?"
>
> A: "Very carefully"

Trying the usual suspects (linear, polynomial, RBF) and using whichever works the best really is sound advice for someone trying to get the most accurate predictive model they can. For what it's worth it's a common criticism of SVMs that they seem to have a lot of parameters that you need to tune empirically. So at least you're not alone.

If you really want to design a kernel for a specific problem then you are right, it is a machine learning problem all in itself. It's called the 'model selection problem'. I'm not exactly an expert myself here, but the best source of insight into kernel methods for me was the book '[Gaussian Processes](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/)' by Rasumussen and Williams (it's freely available online), particularly chapters 4 and 5. I'm sorry that I can't say much more than 'read this huge book full of maths' but it's a complicated problem and they do a really good job of explaining it.

Comment: You're lucky I'm not afraid of maths :) Even better that the contests of this book are online.

Comment: @Bean I think further questions of this type would best be directed at http://metaoptimize.com/qa/ . It's a smaller community but there a lot more machine learning experts there.

Answer (score 6):

(For anyone not familiar with the use of kernel functions in Machine Learning, kernels just maps the input vectors (data points that comprise the data set) into a higher-dimensional space, aka, the "Feature Space". The SVM then finds a separating hyperplane with the maximal margin (distance between the hyperplane and the support vectors) in this transformed space.)

Well, start with *kernels that are known to work* with SVM classifiers to solve the problem of interest. In this case, we know that the ***RBF*** (radial basis function) kernel w/ a trained SVM, cleanly separates XOR. You can write an RBF function in Python this way:

```
def RBF():
    return NP.exp(-gamma * NP.abs(x - y)**2)
```

In which *gamma* is 1/number of features (columns in the data set), and x, y are a Cartesian pair.

(A radial basis function module is also in **scipy.interpolate.Rbf**)

Second, if what you are after is not just using available kernel functions to solve classification/regression problems, but instead you want to build your own, i would suggest first studying how the choice of kernel function and the parameters inside those functions affect classifier performance. The small group of kernel functions in common use with SVM/SVC, is the best place to start. This group is comprised of (aside from RBF):

- linear kernel
- polynomial
- sigmoid

Comment: How can we determine ahead of time whether a kernel "cleanly separates" anything? Certainly there's more principle to it than folk lore and guess-and-check. Are you saying that we approximate the best kernel with certain combinations of linear/polynomial/sogmoid kernels? Because that sounds like a machine learning problem all in itself, even if we restrict ourselves to one class of kernels.

Comment: No. Here, kernels are *not* relied upon to separate the data--but rather to project the data into a higher-dimensional feature space. Second, i mentioned a simple empirical study not "folklore." E.g, a simple study: the same data, same SVM parameters, and kernel choice is the only tunable parameter; to measure the effect of the simplest kernels on SVM classifier performance ).

Comment: You said, "start with kernels that are known to work," which sounds like folk lore to me. And the point of the kernel _is_ to separate the data via that projection, otherwise there would be no separating hyperplane. My question is whether there is any theoretical reason for picking linear/poly/sigmoid/rbf kernels for a given problem, and how does one combine them to fit any known (spacial) properties of the problem. You answer is "empirical study," which is really just a fancy way to say guess and check.

Comment: I don't find anything wrong with doug's answer, considering your question is rather generic in some respects. Passing all kernels that are known to solve some types of problems as parameters in grid search would be a perfectly fine approach, perhaps using nested crossvalidation with same algo (SVC) changing only the kernel, as he suggests in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to study the data: how would I separate the points in the XOR problem? When I started studying about M.L. in general, and SVM in particular that is what I did, took toy problem, draw it by hand, and try to separate the classes.

When I looked at the XOR problem the firs time, it occurred to me that both purple points (below, left) have X and Y of the same sign, in one case negative in one positive, whereas both green points have X and Y of opposite signs. Therefore, the squared sum of X and Y would be 0 (or very small with a bit of noise in the initial problem) for the green points, and 2 (or nearly 2) for the purple ones. Hence, adding a third coordinate `Z = np.sqrt(np.square(X + Y))` will nicely separate the two sets:

[image: 3D before]
[image: 3D after]

On a side note, `Z` is not too dissimilar formulation from [doug's rbf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998951/designing-a-kernel-for-a-support-vector-machine-xor/5999470#5999470) if you consider that `np.sqrt(np.square(X + Y))` is essentially the same as as `np.abs(X + Y)` in this case.

I do not have access to Crisitanini's paper but I'd approach that problem too in a similar way, starting with a toy version (by the way, [checkerboard code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2169547/1034648) thanks to none other than [doug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66549/doug)):

[image: checkerboard]

A possible intuition here is that the sum of row and column indices for the black squares would be always even, whereas for the white squares would be always odd, so adding as a third dimension something like `(row_index + col_index) % 2` would do the trick in this simple version. In a larger, more complex checkerboard dataset, like this I found on the web:

[image: Cristianini-like?]

things aren't so simple, but perhaps one could cascade clustering to find the the 16 clusters' mean X and Y locations (perhaps using [medoids clustering](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/272351873_NumPy_SciPy_Recipes_for_Data_Science_k-Medoids_Clustering)), then apply a version of the "modulo kernel trick"?

With the disclaimer that I have not worked with a ton of classification problems, so far I have found that in making a toy version of a complex one, I've usually gained a 'numerical' intuition as to the kind of solution that might work.

Finally, as posted in a comment to doug's answer, I don't find anything wrong with an [empirical approach like his](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998951/designing-a-kernel-for-a-support-vector-machine-xor#comment6930399_5999470), studying the performance of all possible kernels by passing them to grid search in nested crossvalidation with the same algorithm (SVC) and changing only the kernel. You could add to that approach by plotting the respective margins in the transformed feature spaces: for example, for rbf, using the equation suggested by Doug (and Sebastian Raschka's routine  for plotting decision regions - [cell 13 here](https://github.com/rasbt/python-machine-learning-book-2nd-edition/blob/master/code/ch02/ch02.ipynb)).

**UPDATE October 27/17**
In a conversation on my slack channel, another geophysicist asked me about the case in which the XOR gate is designed as 0s and 1s as opposed to -1s and 1s (the latter being similar to a classic problem in exploration geophysics, hence my initial toy example).

If I were to tackle the XOR gate with 0s and 1s, and did not have at disposal the knowledge about the rbf kernel, in this case too I'd sit and loo at the problem in terms of the coordinates of those problems and see if I could come up with a transformation.

[image: XOR_II]

My first observation here was that the Os sit on the `x=y` line, the Xs on the `x=-y` line, so the difference `x-y` would be 0 (or small with a bit of noise) in on case, +/-1 in the other, respectively. The absolute value would take care of the sign, hence `Z = np.abs(X-Y)` would work. Which, by the way, is very similar to [doug's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5999470/1034648) `rbf = np.exp(-gamma * np.abs(x - y)**2)` (another reason to upvote his answer); and in fact, his rbf is a more general solution, working in all XOR cases.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for some polynomial kernel work through examples and stumbled on this post.  A couple of things that might help if you are still looking are this toolkit (http://www2.fml.tuebingen.mpg.de/raetsch/projects/shogun) which uses multiple kernel learning, where you can choose a wide selection of kernel methods and then the learning will choose the best for the problem, so you don't have to.

An easier more traditional method for your choice of kernel is to use cross-validation with different kernel methods to find the best.

Hope this helps you or anyone else reading around kernel methods.

Comment: Unfortunately I've been looking for a mathematical justification, not an empirical reason. I have yet to find one, so I've sort of resigned it to the bane of applied mathematics and arbitrary parameters.

Answer (score 0):

[XOR_problem](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Edana/MLClass/XOR.pdf) is not linearly-separable, thus e.g. using SVM - use **[polynomial Kernel](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html)**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import sklearn
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# generate the XOR data
##    excluding OR
##    input_data = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]], int)
##    output_data = np.array([[0], [1], [1], [0]], int)

##Using the following code, we will create a simple dataset that has the form of an XOR gate using the logical_xor function from NumPy, where 100 samples will be assigned the class label 1 and 100 samples will be assigned the class label -1, respectively:

np.random.seed(0)
X_xor = np.random.randn(200, 2)
y_xor = np.logical_xor(X_xor[:, 0] > 0, X_xor[:, 1] > 0)
y_xor = np.where(y_xor, 1, -1)

plt.scatter(X_xor[y_xor==1, 0], X_xor[y_xor==1, 1],
             c='b', marker='x', label='1')
plt.scatter(X_xor[y_xor==-1, 0], X_xor[y_xor==-1, 1],
    c='r', marker='x', label='1')
plt.show()

# construct the training and testing split by taking 75% of the data for training
# and 25% for testing
(trainData, testData, trainLabels, testLabels) = train_test_split(X_xor, y_xor, test_size=0.25,
    random_state=42)

# train the linear SVM model, evaluate it, and show the results
##print("[RESULTS] SVM w/ Linear Kernel")
##model = SVC(kernel="linear")
##model.fit(trainData, trainLabels)
##print(classification_report(testLabels, model.predict(testData)))
##print("")

# train the SVM + poly. kernel model, evaluate it, and show the results
print("[RESULTS] SVM w/ Polynomial Kernel")
model = SVC(kernel="poly", degree=2, coef0=1)
model.fit(trainData, trainLabels)
print(classification_report(testLabels, model.predict(testData)))
```

Linear Kernel is commented here - can uncomment to see results of this wrong Kernel usage...
or can use **rbf_Kernel** (e.g.[here](https://towardsdatascience.com/support-vector-machines-learning-data-science-step-by-step-f2a569d90f76)) - to use *Kernel Trick* (described in general at link as Lagrange dual problem)... And [here](https://cedar.buffalo.edu/%7Esrihari/CSE555/SVMs.pdf) are several limitations of SVMs (adding to the fact that SVM cannot acquire new knowledge with new points in real-time dataflow - vs. [perceptron](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-neural-networks-solve-the-xor-problem-59763136bdd7) - SVM need new learning again)

P.S. sklearn still seems more convenient lib for Multi-Class & Multi-Label Classification

Answer (score 0):

A simple kernel function that solves the XOR problem is given by

$(x,y) -> (x,y,xy)$

This is related to the solution given by @MyCarta, since

$(x+y)^2 = x^2 + xy + y^2$

However, the distance to the origin $x^2 + y^2$ is irrelevant for distinguishing the four quadrants, so we can safely ommit it and get a simpler expression.

Here is an illustration of applying such a kernel.

[image]

Clearly, the boundary hyperplane is $z=0$, equivalently $xy=0$, which corresponds to the horizontal and vertical axis, $y=0$ and $x=0$ back in two dimensions.

For the unipolar case, shifting the boundary half a unit in both directions suffices, yielding the hyperbole $\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right) = 0$

The terms needed, $x$, $y$ and $xy$ are included in the quadratic polynomial kernel, but the other terms are not necessary. Therefore, this reduced 3D kernel can be visualized more easily.