# Slicing Pandas DataFrame with a Checkerboard Pattern

Tags: python, pandas

If I have an m x n dataframe, how can I select only the values that make up the dark squares on a checkerboard pattern (note that m may not equal n and either could be bigger, smaller, or equal to the other)? I've tried to mask it by constructing a boolean mask but it isn't elegant. Also note that the values may not all be numerical (there could be text in and column(s) or row(s)) and so strictly using numpy probably would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ogrid to [create a "checkerboard"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2171883/1240268):

```
In [11]: coords = np.ogrid[0:2, 0:3]

In [12]: checkerboard = (coords[0] + coords[1]) % 2 == 0
                                              # use != for an inverted board

In [13]: checkerboard
Out[13]:
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

With that in mind, you can NaN all the other values (which is how I think you mean "select" / mask):

```
In [14]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5 ,6]], columns=list('ABC'))

In [15]: df.where(checkerboard)
Out[15]:
     A    B    C
0  1.0  NaN  3.0
1  NaN  5.0  NaN
```

Note: you can also do this with integers:

```
In [21]: (coords[0] + coords[1]) % 2
Out[21]:
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]])

In [22]: ~(coords[0] + coords[1]) % 2
Out[22]:
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```