# Alternating values in a numpy matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to represent a checkerboard using a numpy matrix comprised of 1s and 0s. It should be able to have dimensions of odd length. Something like

```
a = [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
     [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
     [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

`board = np.resize([0, 1], (3, 5))` works but only because the dimensions are odd, and they could also potentially be even. Is there a fast way to accomplish this?

Comment: Fast or concise?

Comment: If you do `np.resize([0,1], (4, 6))`, for example, the values in each row will alternate correctly, but the beginning of each row will be the same number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169478/how-to-make-a-checkerboard-in-numpy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a checkerboard in numpy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169478/how-to-make-a-checkerboard-in-numpy)

Comment: I thought it was worth asking again, since that answer seems to double the dimensions and therefore can't use odd dimensionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parity of indices:

```
n = 4
p = 5
np.array([[(i+j)%2 for i in range(n)] for j in range(p)])
```

Comment: You can use the same trick in a vectorized numpy fashion instead of list comps, something like `((np.arange(4)[:,None] + np.arange(5)) % 2)`