# How to make a checkerboard in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I see that a simple checkerboard pattern can be created [fairly concisely with numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51715491/5349476) Does anyone know if a checkerboard where each square may contain multiple values could be created? E.g.:

```
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0
```

Comment: you can make it in numpy, then convert to torch via torch.from_numpy

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no equivalent of [np.indices](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) in PyTorch, you can still find a workaround using a combination of [`torch.arange`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.arange.html), [`torch.meshgrid`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.meshgrid.html), and [`torch.stack`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.stack.html):

```
def indices(h,w):
    return torch.stack(torch.meshgrid(torch.arange(h), torch.arange(w)))
```

This allows you to define a base tensor with a checkboard pattern following your [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169478/how-to-make-a-checkerboard-in-numpy/51715491#51715491):

```
>>> base = indices(2,3).sum(axis=0) % 2
tensor([[0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 1]])
```

Then you can repeat the row end columns with [`torch.repeat_interleave`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.repeat_interleave.html):

```
>>> base.repeat_interleave(2, dim=0).repeat_interleave(2, dim=1)
tensor([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

And you can take the opposite of a given checkboard `x` by computing `1-x`.

---

So you could define a function like this:

```
def checkerboard(shape, k):
    """
        shape: dimensions of output tensor
        k: edge size of square
    """
    h, w = shape
    base = indices(h//k, w//k).sum(dim=0) % 2
    x = base.repeat_interleave(k, 0).repeat_interleave(k, 1)
    return 1-x
```

And try with:

```
>>> checkerboard((4,6), 2)
tensor([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```